# Comparing a Location

Tags: vb.net, position

How do I check if a `Location` is, for example, `x = 100, y = 100`?

```
' Compile error
If Button1.Location = 0, 0 Then
    Button1.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough, does your button moves?

Comment: Thats just an example, what Im trying to do is determine a location and if that location is true it runs a code.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ? thats not what im looking for...

Comment: it is, you just dont know it

Comment: @bto.rdz, no that is not what he's looking for.  The OP did not ask how to determine WHEN the `Location` of the control has changed.  He asked to how to know whether the `Location` is a specific value.  Of course, whatever code you use to determine the `Location` would most likely be placed inside the `LocationChanged` event handler.  Even that would depend on the specific circumstances though, and it certainly doesn't answer the question as asked.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Editing is for improving post with new information, while fixing grammar and formatting. __Do not vandalize your own posts or invalidate existing answers__ by replacing it with a new one - They are called "charmeleon questions", and is not an acceptable behaviour. Instead. Close the question by solving it (accept an answer if one helped, or post the solution as a new answer), and then post a new question. I've rolled back your edit. Please also take a [tour].

Comment: You've changed your question again. **You have added informations you did not know taken from the current answers (`New Point(0, 0)`). You are now asking about a total different problem, that is `StartPosition`!**

Comment: @Joiner someone else has edited that.

Comment: Yes, someone rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 2):

The `Location` property is of type `Point` so you have to compare it to a `Point` value.

If you want a `Point` value with coordinates `(0,0)` then you can use the `Shared` field `Point.Empty`.
If you want other coordinates then you'll have to create a `Point` value yourself.

```
If Button1.Location = New Point(100, 100) Then
    Button1.Enabled = False
End If
```

Alternatively, you could compare the `Top` and `Left` properties, each of which are type `Integer`, separately.

Comment: this makes no sense for me, button1.location stores 1 point, and then you are comparing it to another point (New Point(100,100)), this should never be equal, both are diferent instances, are you sure this works?

Comment: It makes sense ! Don't think that "=" (boolean comparator) always means "same object". `System.Drawing.Point` has an implemented `=` operator that compares `.X` and `.Y` values and returns `True` if they match. To know if two points are the same object, you must use the `Is` comparator at object reference level, or static function `Object.ReferenceEquals(Obj1, Obj2)`.

Comment: @bto.rdz, `Point` is a value type.  Equality for value types inherently means value equality.  Why are you asking me if it works instead of testing it for yourself?

Comment: @fsintegral, the `Object.ReferenceEquals` method for value types is irrelevant.  `ReferenceEquals` works on `Object` references so any value type arguments must be boxed.  Even if you pass the same variable to each parameter, each argument is boxed and you will thus have two different `Object` references.  Even if that wasn't the case, the parameters are passed by value, so a value type would have to have been copied anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. You're right. Thank you for notifying my mistake. I'm sorry, I were used to my custom Point2D Class and forgot that System.Drawing.Point was a `Structure` type, not Object. `Is` and `ReferenceEquals` wont never work on Point. `Object.Equals` on the other hand is the one to use for Structures types to check if each members holds the same values (ie same values for value types, pointing to the same single object instance per object member) The `"="` operator works only for structures that has defined a role for that operator.

Comment: @fsintegral, you should read the documentation for the `Object.Equals` method.  For value types, it is the same as the `=` operator.  The only way to change the behaviour of `Equals` method from the default is to override it and, according to the documentation: "If you override Equals and your development language supports operator overloading, you must overload the equality operator".

Comment: @jmcilhinney. I know :) I said the above to point out the difference between `ReferenceEquals`, `Equals` and `=`, for bto.rdz who haven't tried your code. Yes, overriding Equals means also overloading "=" and GetHashCode, etc. but it's good to know what would happen _if you don't_. Equals will fallback to each member declared type, while using "=" to compare two structures will fail and won't compile. Good code will provide both, but are "=" and "<>"_always_ available for each structure ? I was just trying to explain how it works to bto.rdz, but my poor level of english wouldn't help I guess.

Comment: @jmcilhinney : So in the end, everything I wrote was meant to lead bto to start understanding how = works along with Equals for Point **structure**, which is the same as Equals. My bad, I made a mistake thinking Point was of object Type... what a mess. Anyway, just to confirm : My `Point2D` class implements IEquatable(Of Point2D) and overloads Equals as well as providing static "=" and "<>" operators. ;) **EDIT : I wasn't saying you should use Equals in your answer !!** :) Both produce the very same result for Point Structure.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that what you actually want to know is not what I read and what I provided an answer for previously.  I'm not sure whether that's your fault, someone else's fault roa combination of the two.  Either way, I will now answer the question of how to centre a form if it is located in the top-left of its containing window.

Firstly, while creating a new `Point` from (0,0) is not exactly wrong, it's more correct to use `Point.Empty`.

As for the actual issue, it's useless to set the `StartPosition` after you've called `Show` because `StartPosition` represents the position in which the form starts.  If it's already been shown then it's already started so any change to `StartPosition` will have no effect.

You need to position the form manually by setting its `Location` explicitly, based on the relation between its size and that of the window you're positioning it relative too.  The fact that you're using `CenterParent` suggests that that's not the screen, so you'll need to qualify that if you want a specific example.  You shouldn't need a specific example though, because it's simple arithmetic of the sort taught in primary school.

Comment: Well, I'm way younger than you think, and I haven't gone to school for this language, I've been self-teaching myself, can you please show me an example if you can?

Comment: Although, I have a boolean thats set to true, and what I'm trying to do is, if its true it makes form show up in center, but the startposition code isnt working... `If My.Settings.NewUser = True Then StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen`

Comment: First you told us you care about the `Location` of the form and now you tell us that you care about the value of a setting. It would be nice if you didn't keep moving the goal posts. The fact that you have the form setting its own `StartPosition` suggests that you didn't really read what I posted in my answer. The only place that such code could be of use would be in the form's constructor. Is that where you've put it?  If not then it's useless. Normally you'd be setting the `StartPosition` from outside the form, not inside, in the code that creates the form and calls `Show` or `ShowDialog`.

Comment: I said that, if you want an example, you're going to have to be specific about what the form is being centred against, i.e. the screen, an MDI parent or a sibling form.  That said, if you're actually trying to specify where the form first appears then you don't need an example of setting the `Location` because setting the `StartPosition` properly will work.

Comment: You have no idea how old I think you are but I do assume that anyone who is capable of programming is past the age where they learn addition and subtraction in school.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Button1.Location.X = 0 And Button1.Location.Y = 0 Then
    Button1.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: if you don't elaborate your answer, how that's work than might be your answer will be not consider as a useful answer. So when you add code, I advice to you, please explain your code, so that might be useful for other user. Thanks.

Comment: @Odedra _This does not provide an answer to the question._ does not mean _useful answer_.

Comment: Why use `Location.X` and `Location.Y` when you can use `Left` and `Top`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I just upvoted to remove downvote.

Comment: Does not answer my question.

Comment: @Greg [Because you edited it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824897/comparing-a-location#comment42291881_26824897)